# How to disable the refactoring menu arrow/popup in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Can anyone point me to the option in Visual Studio 2019 that disables the little arrow popup when you hover over function names et al? This is C++, if it matters. The tooltip calls it the refactoring menu, but I haven't been able to find anything through Google. Thanks for the help.

[image: Menu popup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any information about the `refactoring menu` in the Microsoft DCs. This looks like a VS plugin. If you have installed the plugin, you can turn it off in the plugin settings. If you have installed Visual Assist, you could disable the floating button in the options dialog of Visual Assist.

[image]

If it doesn't work or you haven't installed the plugin, I suggest that you could reset the VS in `Tools->Import and Export Settings..->Reset all settings`.
[image]

Comment: You know, I swear that I tried turning off VAX when I was trying to figure this out, but clearly I didn't. Thanks for pointing me to the right option.